# How to compute the distance between neighbouring peaks in python?

Tags: python, signal-processing

I have been playing around with the scipy find_peaks() function. I would be interested in finding the vertical distance between a peak and its side lobes, but so far I haven’t been able to find it with the find_peaks() function.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: If you know the location of the peak, you know the argument for which the function peaks. Feed the argument to the function. Now you know the value at the peak. Take the difference between the function values at the two peaks in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more usual to look at [`peak_prominences()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.peak_prominences.html#scipy.signal.peak_prominences) than the difference between the height of the peak and adjacent peaks.

That being said, [`scipy.signal.find_peaks()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) returns the x-indices of the peaks that it finds, which you can use to determine the heights at each peak.

Identify the highest peak (`numpy.max`/`numpy.argmax`) then take the peak before (`index-1`) and after (`index+1`), which correspond to the sidelobes. Choose an algorithm to work out the height you're interested in e.g. `difference = peak - mean(sidelobes)` and voila!